# Visual Studio PATH Setting Seems to not be Working

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can't Visual Studio find my DLL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953843/why-cant-visual-studio-find-my-dll)

I've been trying to use the "VC++ Directories" to set the path to a dll I want to use. I add the path to the "Executable Directories" for the Debug configuration, but when I try to debug the project I get the message saying that the dll cannot be found.

If I copy the dll to the debug folder then debug it works. I'm sure the directory is correct. There must be something I've forgotten to do or did wrong. How do I use the "VC++ Directories" to get the dll?

Any help would be appreciated,
Kevin

Comment: that explains the problem, thanks.