# How to use interface pointer exported by C++ DLL in C#

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

I have a DLL written in C++, which exports a function CreateRisk. The function returns an interface pointer, as follows:

```
extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) IRisk* __stdcall CreateRisk()
    {
        return new  Risk();


    }
}
```

IRisk is derived from IUnknown and has a custom method Calculate:

```
class IRisk: public IUnknown                               
{
public:
    virtual int __stdcall Calculate(int i,double s) = 0;  
};
```

the class Risk implements IRisk interfaces (the implementation is omitted here).

What I want  is to call the function CreateRisk in c# and obtain a reference to IRisk.

I defined a wrapper interface in c#

```
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]        
    public interface IRisk
    {
        [PreserveSig]                                            
        int Calculate(int i,double s);
    }
```

and I added a dll entry in C#

```
    [DllImport("Risk.dll")]
    extern static IntPtr CreateRisk();
```

I can call CreateRisk in C# and obtain a value type of IntPtr.  Is there any way to marshal the IntPtr to the c# IRisk interface so that I can call the Calculate method in C#?

I have tried Marshal.GetIUnknownForObjectInContext,Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown, but to no avail.

I know creating a COM component can do it. However, COM component needs to be registered with the system. I want to avoid those troubles and let C# use the interface exported by the C++ dll directly.

PS:

The following is my Risk class implementation:

```
class IRisk : public IUnknown                               
{
public:
    virtual int __stdcall Calculate(int i,double y ) = 0;  
};

class Risk:public IRisk
{
    int count;
public:
    Risk();
    virtual int __stdcall Calculate( int i ,double y);
    virtual ULONG __stdcall AddRef();
    ULONG __stdcall Release();
    HRESULT __stdcall QueryInterface(const IID& riid,void **ppvObject);
};

Risk::Risk(){
    count=0;
}

ULONG __stdcall Risk::AddRef()
{
    return ++count;
}
ULONG __stdcall Risk::Release()
{
    return --count;
}
HRESULT __stdcall Risk::QueryInterface(const IID& riid,void **ppvObject) {
    *ppvObject=this;
    AddRef();
    return S_OK;
}
int __stdcall Risk::Calculate(int i ,double y) {
    return (int)(i+y);
}
```

Comment: Try to put Risk.dll in the same directory as your .NET assembly; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8836093/how-can-i-specify-a-dllimport-path-at-runtime

Comment: @fableal If there was a problem with the location of the native DLL, then Guiyun would not get as far as receiving the return value from `CreateRisk`.

Answer (score 2):

The following will work:

```
[DllImport("Risk.dll")]
extern static IRiskAssessment CreateRisk();
```

You will need to add a GUID to the interface:

```
[Guid("your GUID goes here")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]        
public interface IRiskAssessment
{
    [PreserveSig]                                            
    int Calculate(int i,double s);
}
```

Obviously you need to use the same GUID in the C# code as was used in the C++ code!

**Update**

Looking at your C++ COM object implementation, the obvious fault is in `QueryInterface`. You must not return `S_OK` for all GUIDs. Only return `S_OK` for the interfaces you implement. Return `E_NOINTERFACE` for the others.

Comment: David, thanks for your quick reply. I added a GUID to the interface. When CreateRisk is called, it throws a AccessViolationException, saying "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory has been corrupted ". I do not have a GUID defined in C++ since I do not use a TypeLib although this interface is completely COM compatible.

Comment: You will need to define a GUID in the C++ code. You don't need a type lib, you just need to implement `QueryInterface` to respond to the GUID. You do not need to register a COM object. I didn't when I tested this code. Is it possible that your implementation of IUnknown is broken?

Comment: David, I add my Risk class implementation in C++ at the end of the original question. The reason I do not use a GUID is because the class only supports one interface and I always returns the interface regardless of the GUID. Something wrong with the implementation?

Comment: Well, it returns `S_OK` whenever you call `QueryInterface`. That's wrong. Only return `S_OK` for interfaces that you actually support. This link shows you how to do it: http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/com-tech/activex/tutorials/article.php/c5567/Step-by-Step-COM-Tutorial.htm#Step5

Comment: After revising the QueryInterface implementation, the exception is gone. David, I really appreciate it. What puzzles me is that why I should need to take care of the case of E_NOINTERFACE? Is that because .NET tries to query other common interface when doing the marshalling?

Comment: That's the obvious explanation, but I don't know for sure. It always pays to follow the rules with QI.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Do feel free to accept the answer!  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would use [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) to generate a C# interface for your C++ code, saves you a lot of troubles. Also, I think your assembly may have to be compiled in [mixed-mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691325/c-cli-mixed-mode-dll-creation), or as a managed assembly.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. There is in fact no need for mixed-mode. It's no trouble at all to pinvoke to functions that return COM interfaces.