# DLLImport path C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I would like to import my DLL inside my C# class but instead of this:

```
[DllImport(@"C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\KeyDll\Debug\DLLWrap.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "?DivSet@MyCall@MyFunc@@SAPADPAD@Z")]
```

I would like to locate the path within the project like so:

```
[DllImport(@"...\Debug\DLLWrap.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "?DivSet@MyCall@MyFunc@@SAPADPAD@Z")]
```

So that it looks in the local folder the solution is in.

Any suggestions??

Regards

Comment: Add appropriate tags, Winforms or WPF?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I specify a \[DllImport\] path at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8836093/how-can-i-specify-a-dllimport-path-at-runtime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use relative urls like:

```
[DllImport("DLLWrap.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "?DivSet@MyCall@MyFunc@@SAPADPAD@Z")]
```

Your application will search working directory (your local folder) for the file by default.

In Winforms, you can always ensure it uses your Working Directory by

```
[DllImport(Application.StartupPath + "\\DLLWrap.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "?DivSet@MyCall@MyFunc@@SAPADPAD@Z")]
```

Comment: Thanks do you know which folder it looks in for this? Is it the same folder as the .sln file or is it inside where the .csproj it?

Comment: No, your debug folder

Comment: Ah I see thnaks! I would upvote you but I do not have enough "karma"

Comment: You cannot put an expression such as `Application.StartupPath + "\\DLLWrap.dll"` into an attribute. It requires a constant string.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the properties of the DLL to be 'Content' and 'Copy Always'

Reference the DLL in your P/Invoke statements as @"DLLWrap.dll"