# Relative Path for C# DLLImport Attribute when DLL is built in same solution file

Tags: c#, c, dll, dllimport, dllexport

I have a C# solution file that has 2 projects in it, `Simulator` and `ProfileParser`. `ProfileParser` is a C dll project that builds the C code as a .dll. I then use the `DLLImport` attribute in the `Simulator` project to call that code.

Here is a sample of how I use the `DLLImport` attribute:

```
[DllImport("C:\\Simulator\\Debug\\ProfileParser.dll", EntryPoint = "fun1", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern UInt32
        fun1(temp_mC, soc);
```

My question is: how do I specify a relative path opposed to a absolute path for this so I can run the application anywhere?

Comment: Have you tried the usual variants that are recognized by Windows, like `.\Simulator\\Debug\\ProfileParser.dll` and `Simulator\\Debug\\ProfileParser.dll`?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/8861895

Comment: Perfect, that link helped a ton. Thank you!