# Importing an unmanaged DLL in C# when name is not known at compile time

Tags: c#, dll

I am hoping this is a simple question but I have not been able to find the solution in my searching.  I have a C# application that needs to load data from several DLLs.  Each DLL is guaranteed to have the same function foo(). But I want these DLLs to be plug and play at run time.  The way I usually handle DLLs (where I know the name) is using:

```
[DllImport("my_dll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int foo();
```

How do I do this with a dynamic string for a file name instead (e.g., "my_dll_3934.dll")? Also, there may be more than 1 dll that must be loaded that matches the same signature (e.g., "my_dll_3934.dll" and "my_dll_3935.dll").

The DLLs that will be used are generated by me but I want the end-user to just drop the DLL in as updates/new dlls become available without updating the application.  I will be doing appropriate error checking and exception handling.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Take a look at this Q&A...I think that the one that haves 11 votes would fill your requirements :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8836093/how-can-i-specify-a-dllimport-path-at-runtime

Comment: I don't have a code example immediately, so I'll post this as a comment rather than a solution, but I think you'll need to explore LoadLibrary() and then GetProcAddress() to accomplish this in a dynamic scenario such as that you describe. You can pass a string to LoadLibrary, get a handle to the module, then use GetProcAddress to find the function.

Comment: Also do not forget that if that answer helps you, give it un up vote!

Comment: Thank you @Hackerman.  I've done the library handle/proc address on the C++ side but I couldn't seem to get it to work on C# side.  The answer you suggested showed me what I needed.  I have upvoted his response.

Comment: I'm glad to help @JLB

Answer (score 0):

Answer to my question can be found here:

[How can I specify a [DllImport] path at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8836093/how-can-i-specify-a-dllimport-path-at-runtime)

in the comment by user Ran.  Thanks to Hackerman for pointing me to the correct solution.

Comment: Don't do that Either delete your question or flag the question as a duplicate for moderators pointing at the other question

Comment: Sorry.  Didn't know.  Should I delete the answer?

Comment: Because I already closed your question as a duplicate I don't think it is nessesary.