# Loading c++ assembly from dotnet core works with DllImport but not Assembly.LoadFrom

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am loading a c++ assembly in my Dotnet core 3.1 application.

If I use DllImport, I can load and use the assembly as expected.

```
[DllImport(
    "lib/mylibrary.dll",
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl,
    EntryPoint = "MyEndpoint"
)]
```

However, I want to select the appropriate library for the platform, windows or linux. I tried loading the DLL dynamically using `System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom` but this gives the error `Bad IL Format`.

I have tried a few different ways, but all give the same error

// read bytes

```
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("lib/myLibrary.dll");
var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(bytes); //bad IL format
```

// Load From

```
 var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom("lib/myLibrary.dll"); //bad IL format
```

//Load from assembly path

```
var assembly = System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath("lib/myLibrary.dll"); //bad IL format
```

//From embedded resource

```
var stream = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("my-library.manifestname.dll");
var assembly System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromStream(stream); //bad IL format
```

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:

solution:

```
static class MyWrapper
{
  static MyWrapper {
    // The linked solution suggests setting the dll path using kernel32, this only works for windows. Set Environment.CurrentDirectory instead.
    if(RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
    {
        Environment.CurrentDirectory = "lib/windows";
    }
    else
    {
        Environment.CurrentDirectory = "lib/unix";
    }
  }
  ...
  [DllImport(
    "my_library", //IMPORTANT: drop the extension to preserve compatibility between dylib, dll, so, etc.
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl,
    EntryPoint = "MyEntryPoint"
  )]
}
```

Comment: You have a native DLL, not a .Net assembly.

Comment: @GSerg *facepalm* time for a coffee i think. I'll that solution, looks like it should help

Answer (score 1):

`Assembly.LoadFrom` and all the other overloads you are using deal with managed assemblies and not native libraries.

`DllImport` is just a clever way to hide a lot of machinery, in fact your native library must be loaded, presumably via `LoadLibrary`, then the runtime needs to bind the method information declared in your class to exported function in your native library, finally the runtime needs to make the runtime association between your method and the function, including the marshaling.

If you would like to emulate what the runtime does under the hood, you can read [this](https://studiofreya.com/2016/02/16/how-to-dynamically-load-native-dlls-from-csharp/) document which gives you an idea about the whole process. Please note that this refers to net standard.

Keep in mind the `DllImport` is cross platform, while your own implementation must be declined for bitness (e.g. x64, x86, arm...) and supported platforms (e.g. linux, windows, macos...) and each of them has its own quirks. For this, see [How can I specify a [DllImport] path at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8861895).