# Error MSB8011 Failed to register output. Please try enabling Per-user Redirection or register the component from a command prompt

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am getting the below error when i am building my C++ project from Visual Studio 2017.

```
Error   MSB8011 Failed to register output. Please try enabling Per-user Redirection or register the component from a command prompt with elevated permissions. 
drvutil C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets 1808    5   Build
```

Please help me what are the settings required to resolve the error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solving error MSB8011: Failed to register output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477117/solving-error-msb8011-failed-to-register-output)