# How to build libmpg123 using the Visual C++ port with YASM?

Tags: command-line, yasm

According to the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15225894/windows-mp3-decode-library-c-c) question, the first method says that you *can* build it from the source code (provided in the *ports* folder) which is more flexible than the second option (which can only generate a dynamic library, not a **static** one).

Me, knowing that I want to compile Mpg123 statically for SDL2 have to go through this so-called **painful** method to get a static library (only a `.lib` and not a `.dll`) out of it.

I installed YASM and set it up in the environment variables as it said and tried to build the source code. Unfortunately, for me, it turned out a *fail* (**obviously**).

The error is in the form of a single error (a *command-line* error to be specific) and it is tremendously huge to understand, so can you please help me to understand this error given below (seems that there is absolutely no article on how to build mpg123 from source code, which is the reason for me to turn here for help in the end).

Here comes the "**only**" error (It is a single error but way too complicated to put inside quoted blocks so it is inside a code snippet...):

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   MSB3073 The command "cl /I "..\..\.." /I "D:\SDL2\Dependencies\mpg123-1.25.10\mpg123-1.25.10\ports\MSVC++\2015\win32\libmpg123\..\..\..\..\..\src"  /EP /TC "D:\SDL2\Dependencies\mpg123-1.25.10\mpg123-1.25.10\ports\MSVC++\2015\win32\libmpg123\..\..\..\..\..\src\libmpg123\dct36_3dnow.S" /nologo     "Win32\Debug_x86\dct36_3dnow.asm"
yasm -a x86 -p gas -r raw -f win32 -g null -m x86 -o  "Win32\Debug_x86\dct36_3dnow.o" "Win32\Debug_x86\dct36_3dnow.asm"

cl /I "..\..\.." /I "D:\SDL2\Dependencies\mpg123-1.25.10\mpg123-1.25.10\ports\MSVC++\2015\win32\libmpg123\..\..\..\..\..\src"  /EP /TC "D:\SDL2\Dependencies\mpg123-1.25.10\mpg123-1.25.10\ports\MSVC++\2015\win32\libmpg123\..\..\..\..\..\src\libmpg123\dct36_3dnowext.S" /nologo     "Win32\Debug_x86\dct36_3dnowext.asm"
yasm -a x86 -p gas -r raw -f win32 -g null -m x86 -o  "Win32\Debug_x86\dct36_3dnowext.o" "Win32\Debug_x86\dct36_3dnowext.asm"

cl /I "..\..\.." /I "D:\SDL2\Dependencies\mpg123-1.25.10\mpg123-1.25.10\ports\MSVC++\2015\win32\libmpg123\..\..\..\..\..\src"  /EP /TC "D:\SDL2\Dependencies\mpg123-1.25.10\mpg123-1.25.10\ports\MSVC++\2015\win32\libmpg123\..\..\..\..\..\src\libmpg123\dct36_sse.S" /nologo     "Win32\Debug_x86\dct36_sse.asm"
yasm -a x86 -p gas -r raw -f win32 -g null -m x86 -o  "Win32\Debug_x86\dct36_sse.o" "Win32\Debug_x86\dct36_sse.asm"

cl /I "..\..\.." /I "D:\SDL2\Dependencies\mpg123-1.25.10\mpg123-1.25.10\ports\MSVC++\2015\win32\libmpg123\..\..\..\..\..\src"  /EP /TC "D:\SDL2\Dependencies\mpg123-1.25.10\mpg123-1.25.10\ports\MSVC++\2015\win32\libmpg123\..\..\..\..\..\src\libmpg123\dct64_3dnow.S" /nologo     "Win32\Debug_x86\dct64_3dnow.asm"
yasm -a x86 -p gas -r raw -f win32 -g null -m x86 -o  "Win32\Debug_x86\dct64_3dnow.o" "Win32\Debug_x86\dct64_3dnow.asm"

cl /I "..\..\.." /I "D:\SDL2\Dependencies\mpg123-1.25.10\mpg123-1.25.10\ports\MSVC++\2015\win32\libmpg123\..\..\..\..\..\src"  /EP /TC "D:\SDL2\Dependencies\mpg123-1.25.10\mpg123-1.25.10\ports\MSVC++\2015\win32\libmpg123\..\..\..\..\..\src\libmpg123\dct64_3dnowext.S" /nologo     "Win32\Debug_x86\dct64_3dnowext.asm"
yasm -a x86 -p gas -r raw -f win32 -g null -m x86 -o  "Win32\Debug_x86\dct64_3dnowext.o" "Win32\Debug_x86\dct64_3dnowext.asm"

cl /I "..\..\.." /I "D:\SDL2\Dependencies\mpg123-1.25.10\mpg123-1.25.10\ports\MSVC++\2015\win32\libmpg123\..\..\..\..\..\src"  /EP /TC "D:\SDL2\Dependencies\mpg123-1.25.10\mpg123-1.25.10\ports\MSVC++\2015\win32\libmpg123\..\..\..\..\..\src\libmpg123\dct64_mmx.S" /nologo     "Win32\Debug_x86\dct64_mmx.asm"
yasm -a x86 -p gas -r raw -f win32 -g null -m x86 -o  "Win32\Debug_x86\dct64_mmx.o" "Win32\Debug_x86\dct64_mmx.asm"

cl /I "..\..\.." /I "D:\SDL2\Dependencies\mpg123-1.25.10\mpg123-1.25.10\ports\MSVC++\2015\win32\libmpg123\..\..\..\..\..\src"  /EP /TC "D:\SDL2\Dependencies\mpg123-1.25.10\mpg123-1.25.10\ports\MSVC++\2015\win32\libmpg123\..\..\..\..\..\src\libmpg123\dct64_sse.S" /nologo     "Win32\Debug_x86\dct64_sse.asm"
yasm -a x86 -p gas -r raw -f win32 -g null -m x86 -o  "Win32\Debug_x86\dct64_sse.o" "Win32\Debug_x86\dct64_sse.asm"

cl /I "..\..\.." /I "D:\SDL2\Dependencies\mpg123-1.25.10\mpg123-1.25.10\ports\MSVC++\2015\win32\libmpg123\..\..\..\..\..\src"  /EP /TC "D:\SDL2\Dependencies\mpg123-1.25.10\mpg123-1.25.10\ports\MSVC++\2015\win32\libmpg123\..\..\..\..\..\src\libmpg123\dct64_sse_float.S" /nologo     "Win32\Debug_x86\dct64_sse_float.asm"
yasm -a x86 -p gas -r raw -f win32 -g null -m x86 -o "Win32\Debug_x86\dct64_sse_float.o" "Win32\Debug_x86\dct64_sse_float.asm"

cl /I "..\..\.." /I "D:\SDL2\Dependencies\mpg123-1.25.10\mpg123-1.25.10\ports\MSVC++\2015\win32\libmpg123\..\..\..\..\..\src"  /EP /TC "D:\SDL2\Dependencies\mpg123-1.25.10\mpg123-1.25.10\ports\MSVC++\2015\win32\libmpg123\..\..\..\..\..\src\libmpg123\equalizer_3dnow.S" /nologo     "Win32\Debug_x86\equalizer_3dnow.asm"
yasm -a x86 -p gas -r raw -f win32 -g null -m x86 -o "Win32\Debug_x86\equalizer_3dnow.o" "Win32\Debug_x86\equalizer_3dnow.asm"

cl /I "..\..\.." /I "D:\SDL2\Dependencies\mpg123-1.25.10\mpg123-1.25.10\ports\MSVC++\2015\win32\libmpg123\..\..\..\..\..\src"  /EP /TC "D:\SDL2\Dependencies\mpg123-1.25.10\mpg123-1.25.10\ports\MSVC++\2015\win32\libmpg123\..\..\..\..\..\src\libmpg123\getcpuflags.S" /nologo     "Win32\Debug_x86\getcpuflags.asm"
yasm -a x86 -p gas -r raw -f win32 -g null -m x86 -o "Win32\Debug_x86\getcpuflags.o" "Win32\Debug_x86\getcpuflags.asm"

cl /I "..\..\.." /I "D:\SDL2\Dependencies\mpg123-1.25.10\mpg123-1.25.10\ports\MSVC++\2015\win32\libmpg123\..\..\..\..\..\src"  /EP /TC "D:\SDL2\Dependencies\mpg123-1.25.10\mpg123-1.25.10\ports\MSVC++\2015\win32\libmpg123\..\..\..\..\..\src\libmpg123\synth_3dnow.S" /nologo     "Win32\Debug_x86\synth_3dnow.asm"
yasm -a x86 -p gas -r raw -f win32 -g null -m x86 -o "Win32\Debug_x86\synth_3dnow.o" "Win32\Debug_x86\synth_3dnow.asm"

cl /I "..\..\.." /I "D:\SDL2\Dependencies\mpg123-1.25.10\mpg123-1.25.10\ports\MSVC++\2015\win32\libmpg123\..\..\..\..\..\src"  /EP /TC "D:\SDL2\Dependencies\mpg123-1.25.10\mpg123-1.25.10\ports\MSVC++\2015\win32\libmpg123\..\..\..\..\..\src\libmpg123\synth_3dnowext.S" /nologo     "Win32\Debug_x86\synth_3dnowext.asm"
yasm -a x86 -p gas -r raw -f win32 -g null -m x86 -o "Win32\Debug_x86\synth_3dnowext.o" "Win32\Debug_x86\synth_3dnowext.asm"

cl /I "..\..\.." /I "D:\SDL2\Dependencies\mpg123-1.25.10\mpg123-1.25.10\ports\MSVC++\2015\win32\libmpg123\..\..\..\..\..\src"  /EP /TC "D:\SDL2\Dependencies\mpg123-1.25.10\mpg123-1.25.10\ports\MSVC++\2015\win32\libmpg123\..\..\..\..\..\src\libmpg123\synth_i586.S" /nologo     "Win32\Debug_x86\synth_i586.asm"
yasm -a x86 -p gas -r raw -f win32 -g null -m x86 -o "Win32\Debug_x86\synth_i586.o" "Win32\Debug_x86\synth_i586.asm"

cl /I "..\..\.." /I "D:\SDL2\Dependencies\mpg123-1.25.10\mpg123-1.25.10\ports\MSVC++\2015\win32\libmpg123\..\..\..\..\..\src"  /EP /TC "D:\SDL2\Dependencies\mpg123-1.25.10\mpg123-1.25.10\ports\MSVC++\2015\win32\libmpg123\..\..\..\..\..\src\libmpg123\synth_mmx.S" /nologo     "Win32\Debug_x86\synth_mmx.asm"
yasm -a x86 -p gas -r raw -f win32 -g null -m x86 -o "Win32\Debug_x86\synth_mmx.o" "Win32\Debug_x86\synth_mmx.asm"

cl /I "..\..\.." /I "D:\SDL2\Dependencies\mpg123-1.25.10\mpg123-1.25.10\ports\MSVC++\2015\win32\libmpg123\..\..\..\..\..\src"  /EP /TC "D:\SDL2\Dependencies\mpg123-1.25.10\mpg123-1.25.10\ports\MSVC++\2015\win32\libmpg123\..\..\..\..\..\src\libmpg123\synth_sse.S" /nologo     "Win32\Debug_x86\synth_sse.asm"
yasm -a x86 -p gas -r raw -f win32 -g null -m x86 -o "Win32\Debug_x86\synth_sse.o" "Win32\Debug_x86\synth_sse.asm"

cl /I "..\..\.." /I "D:\SDL2\Dependencies\mpg123-1.25.10\mpg123-1.25.10\ports\MSVC++\2015\win32\libmpg123\..\..\..\..\..\src"  /EP /TC "D:\SDL2\Dependencies\mpg123-1.25.10\mpg123-1.25.10\ports\MSVC++\2015\win32\libmpg123\..\..\..\..\..\src\libmpg123\synth_sse_float.S" /nologo     "Win32\Debug_x86\synth_sse_float.asm"
yasm -a x86 -p gas -r raw -f win32 -g null -m x86 -o "Win32\Debug_x86\synth_sse_float.o" "Win32\Debug_x86\synth_sse_float.asm"

cl /I "..\..\.." /I "D:\SDL2\Dependencies\mpg123-1.25.10\mpg123-1.25.10\ports\MSVC++\2015\win32\libmpg123\..\..\..\..\..\src"  /EP /TC "D:\SDL2\Dependencies\mpg123-1.25.10\mpg123-1.25.10\ports\MSVC++\2015\win32\libmpg123\..\..\..\..\..\src\libmpg123\synth_stereo_sse_float.S" /nologo     "Win32\Debug_x86\synth_stereo_sse_float.asm"
yasm -a x86 -p gas -r raw -f win32 -g null -m x86 -o "Win32\Debug_x86\synth_stereo_sse_float.o" "Win32\Debug_x86\synth_stereo_sse_float.asm"

cl /I "..\..\.." /I "D:\SDL2\Dependencies\mpg123-1.25.10\mpg123-1.25.10\ports\MSVC++\2015\win32\libmpg123\..\..\..\..\..\src"  /EP /TC "D:\SDL2\Dependencies\mpg123-1.25.10\mpg123-1.25.10\ports\MSVC++\2015\win32\libmpg123\..\..\..\..\..\src\libmpg123\tabinit_mmx.S" /nologo     "Win32\Debug_x86\tabinit_mmx.asm"
yasm -a x86 -p gas -r raw -f win32 -g null -m x86 -o "Win32\Debug_x86\tabinit_mmx.o" "Win32\Debug_x86\tabinit_mmx.asm"

cl /I "..\..\.." /I "D:\SDL2\Dependencies\mpg123-1.25.10\mpg123-1.25.10\ports\MSVC++\2015\win32\libmpg123\..\..\..\..\..\src"  /EP /TC "D:\SDL2\Dependencies\mpg123-1.25.10\mpg123-1.25.10\ports\MSVC++\2015\win32\libmpg123\..\..\..\..\..\src\libmpg123\synth_sse_accurate.S" /nologo     "Win32\Debug_x86\synth_sse_accurate.asm"
yasm -a x86 -p gas -r raw -f win32 -g null -m x86 -o "Win32\Debug_x86\synth_sse_accurate.o" "Win32\Debug_x86\synth_sse_accurate.asm"

cl /I "..\..\.." /I "D:\SDL2\Dependencies\mpg123-1.25.10\mpg123-1.25.10\ports\MSVC++\2015\win32\libmpg123\..\..\..\..\..\src"  /EP /TC "D:\SDL2\Dependencies\mpg123-1.25.10\mpg123-1.25.10\ports\MSVC++\2015\win32\libmpg123\..\..\..\..\..\src\libmpg123\synth_sse_s32.S" /nologo     "Win32\Debug_x86\synth_sse_s32.asm"
yasm -a x86 -p gas -r raw -f win32 -g null -m x86 -o "Win32\Debug_x86\synth_sse_s32.o" "Win32\Debug_x86\synth_sse_s32.asm"

cl /I "..\..\.." /I "D:\SDL2\Dependencies\mpg123-1.25.10\mpg123-1.25.10\ports\MSVC++\2015\win32\libmpg123\..\..\..\..\..\src"  /EP /TC "D:\SDL2\Dependencies\mpg123-1.25.10\mpg123-1.25.10\ports\MSVC++\2015\win32\libmpg123\..\..\..\..\..\src\libmpg123\synth_stereo_sse_accurate.S" /nologo     "Win32\Debug_x86\synth_stereo_sse_accurate.asm"
yasm -a x86 -p gas -r raw -f win32 -g null -m x86 -o "Win32\Debug_x86\synth_stereo_sse_accurate.o" "Win32\Debug_x86\synth_stereo_sse_accurate.asm"

cl /I "..\..\.." /I "D:\SDL2\Dependencies\mpg123-1.25.10\mpg123-1.25.10\ports\MSVC++\2015\win32\libmpg123\..\..\..\..\..\src"  /EP /TC "D:\SDL2\Dependencies\mpg123-1.25.10\mpg123-1.25.10\ports\MSVC++\2015\win32\libmpg123\..\..\..\..\..\src\libmpg123\synth_stereo_sse_s32.S" /nologo     "Win32\Debug_x86\synth_stereo_sse_s32.asm"
yasm -a x86 -p gas -r raw -f win32 -g null -m x86 -o "Win32\Debug_x86\synth_stereo_sse_s32.o" "Win32\Debug_x86\synth_stereo_sse_s32.asm"

:VCEnd" exited with code 1. libmpg123   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets 128
```

It can easily be seen that the error is related to YASM in some way but I don't know ***how***?

I have downloaded YASM from [here](http://yasm.tortall.net) by the way.

**EDIT:**  When I actually tried to compile all the assembly source files using YASM in the Command Prompt, most of them usually said:-

> error: instruction not recognized: 'PREPARE_GOT'
>   error: instruction not recognized: 'GET_GOT'
>   error: instruction not recognized: 'RESTORE_GOT'

*Thank you.*

Comment: You could run each of the individual commands to see which one actually failed.

Comment: @msbit Okay, I followed what you said and added what errors I got (for most of them that is) when I compiled all of them individually using YASM in CMD.

Comment: Hmm, apparently a reported bug (https://sourceforge.net/p/mpg123/bugs/259/). It looks like this hasn't been fixed upstream but the `vcpkg` folks have a patch they apply at build time: https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/blob/master/ports/mpg123/0002-fix-x86-build.patch

Comment: Actually, I'm not very familiar with `vcpkg`, but it looks like you may be able to configure the linking type through the `VCPKG_LIBRARY_LINKAGE` variable, and so may be able to use it to install your library with much less fuss :)

Comment: @msbit Thank you, I never knew that **vcpkg** was this helpful! It can install many different packages which require great effort to build just inside visual studio without having to do *anything* at all. This is something new for me to learn and also for those people who saw this question along with this comment.

Comment: Yep it looks pretty nifty. In terms of getting `mpg123` built as a static library, I think it'd be better (and easier!) to specify `--triplet x86-windows-static` on the command line than to set the linkage variable. Bon chance!

Comment: @msbit You can try going [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/blob/master/docs/examples/using-sqlite.md) for more information based on installing packages. You can do `.\vcpkg install <name_of_pkg>:x86-windows-static` and similar for x64 bit architecture.