# Cannot reference dll from another project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll

I have a dll project that I'm trying to reference into another project. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495795/how-do-i-use-a-third-party-dll-in-visual-studio-c) example or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809948/dll-references-in-visual-c) one, and though I don't get any intellisense error, when I compile I get

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'library.h': No such file or directory
```

So what I did was to add the folder where the lib/dll are located to

```
Linker / General / Additional Library Directories
```

tried also with `Configuration Properties / VC++ Directories / Library Directories`

and added the lib file name to

```
Linker / Input / Additional Dependencies
```

Included as #include < library.h >

Comment: How about additional include directories? This is not a linker problem.

Comment: ***I don't get any intellisense error*** Intellisense is not 100% reliable at detecting errors. Trust the compiler output over Intellisense.

Comment: added the folder path to C/C++ / General / Additional Include Directories with the same result

Comment: ***added the folder path*** Was that the exact folder containing `library.h`? If the path had spaces in it did you quote the path?

Comment: it was the folder containing the lib and dll. doesn't have any spaces, but it is in a totally different location than my current project. do i need to move them?

Comment: That is probably the wrong path. The correct path must contain `library.h`. And you have to quote it if there are spaces in the path.

Comment: do the projects need to be in the same solution?

Comment: No they do not need to be in the same solution.